# Why use past tense for descriptions of a thing that's seen?

Tags: past-tense

In the sentence below, when the author said "the monster **was** seven feet tall and **had** red eyes..." Why were "was" and "had" used? I thought it should be simple tense since it's a fact that the monster is 7 foot tall and he has red eyes.

> Alex Konis, a young driver from South Carolina, claimed a monster
>   attacked him while he was driving along a lonely road. The monster was
>   seven feet tall and had red eyes and scaly skin.

Answer (score 3):

It might be an actual fact that the **monster was seven feet tall and had red eyes** but  all of these facts were reported in the past (claimed a monster attacked him).

So, typically a narrative is reported using the simple past.

When we want [to list](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepast.html) or describe a series of completed actions in the past we use simple past.